# Oracle error log

Tags: linux, oracle

I have run an SQL script under Linux using @xxx.sql but I get the following error :

```
Warning: Function created with compilation errors.
```

The database is in Oracle.
I have used the command SHOW ERROR to get more details and I was wondering if the errors shown are stored in some log file
somewhere?  Any idea?

Comment: Yes, have a look at view `ALL_ERRORS`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit :  I meant more like a log file which stores all sql errors.  I have tried ALL_ERRORS though, it does not work.

Comment: Strange for me it works fine. Error messages are even kept when I have been logged out.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit : You mean you get errors from past executions as well? Don't you know if there exist a log file which keeps all these errors?

Comment: There is no log file that stores that sort of compilation error; USER_ERRORS, ALL_ERRORS and DBA_ERRORS all contain different subsets of the errors. Log in as the owner of the function, compile it and look at ALL_ERRORS - I have never had any problem with this.